# Question about Zuming Feng's 103 Trigonometry Problems

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

In example 1.2 of Zuming Feng's 103 Trigonometry Problems, there is a step in a problem that I don't quite understand. Here is the problem:

> In the trapezoid ABCD (Figure 1.8), $AB | | CD$, $|AB| = 4$ and
>   $|CD| = 10$. Suppose that lines $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at right angles, and that lines
>   $BC$ and $DA$, when extended to point $Q$, form an angle of 45◦. Compute $[ABCD]$,
>   the area of trapezoid $ABCD$.

Here is a diagram:

[image]

An image can be found [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=AUb3thdTTq4C&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=Figure+1.8+103+trigonometry+problems&source=bl&ots=ffJ6Sx1A3d&sig=j3g8T3Nk-1BKbImvZK9ArwFD1TU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS9ZWlo7TVAhWL3YMKHcUjAQsQ6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=Figure%201.8%20103%20trigonometry%20problems&f=false)

In one of the steps it claims that $∠CPD=∠CQD+∠QCP+∠QDP$, why is that? I understand the rest of the steps but just not that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\angle CPD + \angle PCD+\angle PDC = \pi$$

$$\angle CQD +\angle QCD+\angle QDC = \pi$$

and $$\angle QCD =\angle QCP + \angle PCD\quad \& \quad \angle QDC = \angle QDP +\angle PDC$$

The desired result follows at once.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't it be $∠QDC=∠QDP+∠PDC$?

Comment: Absolutely.  Danger of cut and pasting formatted text.